# Unable to download FlexMonkey tool

Tags: flex-monkey

I have tried several times to download the FlexMonkey , but couldn't. Is there someone who was able to download this flexmonkey ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try from;

> github https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=flexmonkey

Some repositories are exported from the old Google code repo `code.google.com/p/flexmonkey` or from;

> https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/flexmonkey-documentation/flexmonkey-5-user-guide/installation-and-setup